# What code should I use to manage a database connected with an android/apple app?

Tags: android, python, ios, mysql, server

I am new in Android development.

I am developing an app that will mainly have:

- Login/Register
- A profile with a picture and some additional information (like age, fav color)
- gps localizations

What programming language should I use to manage my database?
Can I use Python with MySQL or should I use other languages?

App will first be created on Android then iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the backend yourself using any language or if you just want to focus on doing Android and iOS apps then you can also use third party solutions like [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/).